# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar de esta manera una tabla?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Trato de hacer crear una consulta para mostrar en diferentes campos.

```
SELECT p.NombreCompleto AS Nombre
   ,p.grado AS Grado
   ,p.paralelo AS paralelo
   ,SUM(p.efectivo) AS Valor
FROM persona p
WHERE p.NombreCompleto IS NOT NULL
      AND p.Valor != 0.00
GROUP BY p.NombreCompleto
   ,p.grado
   ,p.paralelo
```

Y esto es lo que obtengo:

> ```
> +--------+---------+----------+----------+
> | Nombre |  grado  | paralelo | efectivo |
> +--------+---------+----------+----------+
> | Angie  | Séptimo | A        |      100 |
> | Angie  | Séptimo | A        |      200 |
> +--------+---------+----------+----------+
> ```

Quiero mostrar de esta manera:

> ```
> +--------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
> | Nombre |  grado  | paralelo | efectivoA | efectivoB |
> +--------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
> | Angie  | Séptimo | A        |       100 |       200 |
> +--------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
> ```

Comment: Podrías editar tu pregunta e incluir el código que tienes avanzado

Comment: Es claro la forma de actuar: transponer valores de fila a columnas. Hacerlo es simple si la cantidad de valores de fila se conocen a priori (en el ejemplo son dos filas), pero si la cantidad de filas no se puede determinar entonces se debe escribir la consulta de manera dinámica y al final ejecutar la misma mediante el procedimiento de sistema sp_executesql, esperamos por la aclaración.

Comment: `código`select p.NombreCompleto         AS    Nombre,
  p.grado    AS      Grado,
  p.paralelo   AS      paralelo,
  SUM(cc.Valor)                AS       Valor

from persona p

  where p.NombreCompleto is not null
  and p.Valor != 0.00

  group by 
          p.NombreCompleto, 
   p.grado, 
   p.paralelo

Comment: @RodrigoRodriguez, ¿Cuántos efectivos por persona puede ver? ¿Solo dos: A y B?

Comment: asi es @davlio, con dos es suficiente

Comment: @davlio solo dos efectivos para n cantidad de personas

Comment: @RodrigoRodriguez encuentro que haces `SUM(cc.Valor)` usando el alias `cc.`, ¿De qué tabla es ese alias?

Comment: @davlio me equivoque,  es SUM(p.efectivo)

Comment: @RodrigoRodriguez estoy tratando de reproducir porque te sale 2 filas en tu consulta, pero al revisar tu consulta el `GROUP BY` solo debería generar una fila. Mira: http://rextester.com/UUODLY56401 (Ese link tiene opción para editarla)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

esta fue mi solucion:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (
    Grado VARCHAR(50),
    Codigo VARCHAR(50),
    Nombre VARCHAR(50),
    Detalle VARCHAR(50),
    Valor VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @test
    SELECT 'Tercero','4664','Angie','Descuento','-250.00'
    UNION
    SELECT 'Tercero','4664','Angie','Mensualidad','5000.00'
    UNION
    SELECT 'Tercero','4664','Angie','Fact','-875.00';

--SELECT Detalle,Codigo, Valor FROM @test

select Grado, Codigo, Nombre, Descuento, Mensualidad
from
(
  select Grado, Codigo,Nombre, Valor, Detalle
  from @test
) d
pivot
(
  max(Valor)
  for Detalle in (Descuento, Mensualidad)
) piv;
```